# Time-inhomogeneous Markov Chains

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, markov-chains

I'm trying to find out what is known about time-inhomogeneous ergodic Markov Chains where the transition matrix can vary over time. 
All textbooks and lecture notes I could find initially introduce Markov chains this way but then quickly restrict themselves to the time-homogeneous case where you have one transition matrix.

Obviously, in general such Markov chains might not converge to a unique stationary distribution, but I would be surprised if there isn't a large (sub)class of these chains where convergence is guaranteed. I'm particularly interested in theorems on the mixing time and convergence theorems that state when there exists a stationary distribution.

Comment: Isn't there a stationary convergence iff the transition matrix converge?

Comment: Well, I was wondering whether this is true but couldn't find a reference.

Comment: I'll try to post this on mathoverlow...

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168398/ .  Next time, if you cross-post, please add links to the questions both ways.